# React accessing to array's values using dynamic naming for the variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a simple printing out of the values of an array:

```
export default function App() {
  var data = [{name:'Jhon', age:28, city:'HO'},
            {name:'Onhj', age:82, city:'HN'},
            {name:'Nohj', age:41, city:'IT'}
           ];

    data.map(({name, age}, i) => {
       console.log(name + ' ' + age);
    })
 }
```

Now, I receive the names of the values in another array, how can I print out the values of the array using a variable:

```
    export default function App() {
      var data = [{name:'Jhon', age:28, city:'HO'},
                {name:'Onhj', age:82, city:'HN'},
                {name:'Nohj', age:41, city:'IT'}
               ];
     //Here are the keys of the array
     var colNames =  ['name','age'];
    
        data.map(({colNames}, i) => {
        //So I can do something like
           console.log(colNames[0] + ' ' + colNames[1]);
        })
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, you are trying to destructure `colNames` property from the data object which is not present on the data object.

You can use below snippets to print the values from the data object.

```
export default function App() {
    var data = [{name:'Jhon', age:28, city:'HO'},
           {name:'Onhj', age:82, city:'HN'},
           {name:'Nohj', age:41, city:'IT'}
           ];
    //Here are the keys of the array
    var colNames =  ['name','age'];

    data.map((item, i) => {
        //So I can do something like
        console.log(item[colNames[0]] + ' ' + item[colNames[1]]);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the sense that you want:

```js
export default function App() {
  var data = [{name:'Jhon', age:28, city:'HO'},
            {name:'Onhj', age:82, city:'HN'},
            {name:'Nohj', age:41, city:'IT'}
           ];
  
    // assuming you got the colNames from somewhere..
    data.map(item => {
       const text = colNames.map(c => item[c]).join(' ');
       console.log(text);
    });
}
```